# Dynamically get a running container name created by docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, circleci

When I run my docker-compose, it creates a web container and postgres container.

I want to manually trigger my Django tests to run, via something like

```
docker-compose run web python manage.py test
```

the problem with this is it creates a new container (requiring new migrations to be applied, housekeeping work, etc.)

The option I'm leaning towards it doing something like

```
docker exec -i -t <containerid> python manage.py test
```

This introduces a new issue which is that I must run `docker ps` first to grab the container name.  The whole point of this is to automatically run the tests for each build so it has to be automated, manually running `docker ps` is not a solution.

So is there a way to dynamically grab the container id or is there a better way to do this?  This would not be an issue if you could assign container names in docker-compose

Comment: You can name the container with (e.g.) `--name my_container` when you run it.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/containername

Comment: I know you can do this when running an individual container, but I am using docker-compose

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `docker-compose exec`. It will execute in the already-running container instead of starting a new one.

```
docker-compose exec web python manage.py test
```

Comment: This has never worked for me. docker-compose exec web python manage.py test  "no such command exec"

Comment: and docker exec web python manage.py test "No such container: web"

Comment: @david What version of docker-compose are you using? I have 1.10.0-rc1 and it supports `exec`...

Comment: @david On another system I have an older docker-compose, 1.8.0, it also supports `exec`...

Comment: For some reason I was on 1.5 even though I installed docker-compose 2 months ago.  Anyway I upgraded and can run docker-compose exec now, thanks.

Comment: Remark that docker-compose exec runs in tty mode per default. This leads to a long search for execution problems in Jenkins. For not running in tty use -T as option: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/

Answer (score 33):

While an accepted answer was provided, the answer itself is not really related to the title of this question:

> Dynamically get a running container name created by docker-compose

To dynamically retrieve the name of a container run by docker-compose you can execute the following command:

```
$(docker inspect -f '{{.Name}}' $(docker-compose ps -q web) | cut -c2-)
```

Comment: Or, simpler: `docker compose ps --format '{{.Name}}' web`

Answer (score 10):

You can assign a name to a container using `container_name` option on docker-compose.yml file.

`container_name: container_name`

Then, you can easily run commands in that container using.

`docker exec container_name python manage.py test`.

For more information about docker-compose options, visit the official documentation.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Answer (score 3):

Use `docker-compose ps -q` to find the ID of the container and run the command in that:

`docker exec -it $(docker-compose ps -q) sh`

PS: This will NOT work if you have multiple containers in the docker-compose file.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answer from Toni Van de Voorde, I have found a simpler way to get the container name for a docker compose service:

```
docker compose ps --format '{{.Name}}' <service_name>
```

For example, if the service is named "app":

```
docker compose ps --format '{{.Name}}' app
```