# I can't enter into the mongo db cli in my docker project

Tags: mongodb, bash, docker

I am learning docker and during my project, i can't enter the mongo db with this command:

```
mongo -u "username" -p "mypassword"
```

It throws me this error:

```
bash: mongo: command not found
```

I am not sure what the issue is. I have installed the community edition of mongo db and i also tried different terminals but i can't enter the db.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo.exe not installed in Version 6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't run "mongo" command (mongo shell) on Ubuntu after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73276244/cant-run-mongo-command-mongo-shell-on-ubuntu-after-installation)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please give us a little more information: At first sight, Mongo and Docker are not related. Where are you executing the command? Inside your container? Show us your `Dockerfile` then.

Comment: Hi @ahuemmer you are right. well i created a mongo db in my docker-compose.yml. In the terminal in vs code, i type in the command mongo -u "username" -p "mypassword" and i get the above statet error. 


`version: "3"
services:
  node-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - PORT=3000

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=username
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
    volumes:
      - mongo-db:/data/db

volumes:
  mongo-db:`

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you did the following: Create `docker-compose.yml` as you wrote before. Start `docker compose up`. This will start a container on your system, having mongodb installed in it. It will not affect your "normal" system outside this container. (You can imagine it as kind of a virtual machine, though it is not really the same.) So, if you did not install mongodb on your local host system as well, the error you encounter is quite explicable.

If you want to access the mongodb running within the container, you have two possibilities:

**1. From outside the container (which is the more common use case)**

You will have to install mongo on your regular PC (or anywhere you want to access your db from) as well. Then you would issue `mongo 127.0.0.1:3000`. The `3000` is important as your `docker-compose.yml` says, mongo is listening on port `3000`. Note that you might have to get your network configuration adapted before this works, especially from other PCs, where `127.0.0.1` won't be correct.

**2. From within the container**

Once your container is started, you can also execute a command inside it, like this: `docker exec -it ${container_id} /bin/bash`. You'll have to find out the container's ID beforehand, using something like `docker-compose ps -q`. This will start a bash shell inside the container and "connect" you to it. (If there's no `/bin/bash` installed in the container, this will not work. Try e. g. `/bin/sh` instead.) Now your terminal will be inside the container and just be able to use the commands present there. So, to get back to your local PC, don't forget to issue `exit`.

**Conclusion**

IMHO, the crucial point is, that the physical PC you are working in front of and the container running inside it are almost completely different systems, connected only by the docker daemon and some virtual network access. You'll have to keep that in mind and decide what you want to do/run inside the container and what to do outside, on the host.

[Here](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-mongodb-work-in-docker-how-to-connect-with-mongodb/44763) is a little further reference that might help you. And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69135903/4970679) is about how to find out your container ID in an automated way. (Assuming that you are running just that one container!)